# Is there a way to set limit on a int in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

for example if an int was on 63 and i wanted it to go up to 70 as a max but the commuter did not know how much exactly to add until it was at 70 is there a simple way I could do this?

Comment: Are you taking about rounding up?

Comment: mmm, use subtraction? `if-else` check? not sure what is your goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no number type built into python that does what  you're asking for. Instead, when your value changes you can use `value = min(value, 70)` to make it a maximum of 70.

I'm toying with the idea of objects doing this automatically in this repository https://github.com/tmerr/experimental/tree/master/nconstrain, but it's a little sketchy.

Comment: Could this make a simple health point variable like in Minecraft or Fallout?

Comment: Sure. If you're making a game then after healing or taking damage you could use something like `health = max(0, min(health, 100))` to keep health between 0 and 100.